# Loss of parameters in Spring Cloud OpenFeign GET requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

When using Spring Cloud OpenFeign to make GET requests, there is a certain probability of losing parameters if they are passed as a parameter string in the URL.

The following are the obtained logs, where I have used two interceptors, each declared with @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) and @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE) respectively, in order to ascertain whether the corresponding parameters can be obtained at the beginning and the end.

```
2023-06-07 19:12:05.844 ERROR 19253 [http-nio-7009-exec-5] com.test.HighLogInterceptor highUrl: http://10.0.0.2:7009/test/api/get
2023-06-07 19:12:05.845 ERROR 19253 [http-nio-7009-exec-5] com.test.HighLogInterceptor highUrl: companyId=2023050900000007
2023-06-07 19:12:05.849 ERROR 19253 [http-nio-7009-exec-5] com.test.LowLogInterceptor lowUrl: http://10.0.0.2:7009/test/api/get
2023-06-07 19:12:05.849 ERROR 19253 [http-nio-7009-exec-5] com.test.LowLogInterceptor lowUrl: companyId=2023050900000007
2023-06-07 19:12:05.853 ERROR 19253 [http-nio-7009-exec-5] com.test.config.ExceptionHandlerAdvice org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'companyId' is not present
......
```

Below is my relevant code snippet:

feignClient:

```java
@FeignClient(value = "test")
 public interface TestServerFeign {
    @GetMapping("/api/getCompanyNameByCompanyId") 
    String get(@RequestParam("companyId") String companyId);
 }
```

controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/test/api/get") 
public String get(@RequestParam("companyId") String companyId) {
    if (companyId == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return companyId;
 }
```

It can be confirmed that the parameter is indeed being passed to the server. However, why there are instances when the "id" parameter cannot be obtained remains a question.

I have noticed that when changing the request method to POST, the parameter is not lost.

Comment: You're calling different API: the API exposed is /test/api/get while the feign client is calling /test/api/getCompanyNameByCompanyId